# jsoncpp write json array with only one element

Tags: c++, arrays, jsoncpp

I have a problem in using `jsoncpp`. Code is below:

```
Json::Value content;
for ( int i=0; i < len; ++i)
{
    content["res"].append(strs[i]);
}
```

My case is, when my string vector `strs` only have one element, the final `json` string are like:

```
"res":"a"
```

However, I'm expecting something like:

```
"res":["a"]
```

I hope anyone pull me out, thanks guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved! Thanks for the help from both @dani2442 and @stetoc

I run a little test with code below:

```
Json::Value root, content(Json::arrayValue);
content.append("a");
root["res"]=content;
cout << root.toStyledString() <<endl;
```

the result is :

```
{
    "res" : [ "a" ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize *content* as an array doing this:

```
Json::Value content(Json::arrayValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

afaik content should be defined as `Json::arrayValue` instead of content

Comment: why not? if he declares variable as Json::arrayValue then his function will work properly

Comment: @stetoc your answer forced me to read a lot on meta on the topic of **low quality answer** and **not an answer** identification. While I still have my opinion that your answer could be improved, I revoked **not an answer** flag and admit my mistake. It's a topic discussed widely and coming back like a boomerang but the majority of experienced SO users seem to consider answers similar to yours to be valid answers. They still recommend editing and improving these answers.